# peverify bugs fixed in .NET 4?

Tags: clr, cil, peverify

I have VS .NET 2010 installed, and a class library targeting .NET 3.5. The simple C# fragment below generates verifiable IL under .NET 4.0's peverify, but the IL does not verify using .NET 3.5's peverify.

Were there any peverify bugs fixed in this transition?

```
public static bool IsGenericTypeInstance(this Type typ)
{
    return typ.IsGenericType && !typ.IsGenericTypeDefinition;
}
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllGenericArguments(this Type type)
{
    return type.IsGenericTypeInstance()
         ? type.GetGenericArguments()
               .SelectMany(x => x.IsGenericTypeInstance()
                                ? GetAllGenericArguments(x)
                                : new[] { x })
         : Enumerable.Empty<Type>();
}
```

The error generated is:

```
Error   26  [Sasa.dll : Sasa.Types::<GetAllGenericArguments>b__0]
[offset 0x0000001C][found ref 'System.Collections.IEnumerable']
[expected ref 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Type]']
Unexpected type on the stack.
```

I'm obviously a little concerned since I'm explicitly targeting .NET 3.5, and I don't want runtime verification errors on this platform.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I don't recall, sorry.